# There are hardware recomendation for running a solver for Linear Programing with pyomo and GLPK?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pyomo

I'm creating a model with Pyomo for solving an optimization problem in networking. the solver we are using is GLPK. The idea is that we will have a server that solves a request with the optimization problem information. It may or may not require a considerable amount of time depending on the number of nodes and flows.

For that reason, we are looking for hardware specifications for decreasing the time for finding a solution. The cores and frequency of them is a parameter to regard? maybe Memory or a method to clean the cache?, there are other methods to reduce the time using Pyomo and GLPK solver?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid this question is incredibly broad. Yes, single-core performance is a safe bet while multi-core performance can't do anything in some cases (parallelizing pure LPs / Simplex is not easy), but could in others (Interior-point methods based on good sparse-solvers). This depends on specifics. People might tune on other things first like: 1) Using a better solver (Hint: CoinOR Clp, HiGHS, Glop) 2) Using a better algorithm (Hint: Big LP? Interior-point might be a better idea than simplex). More memory does not speed up things, but not enough memory can slow everything (*trashing*).

Comment: @sascha Thanks for the answer, I will make some performance testing with different AWS machines and different solvers to see if I can improve the perfomance